# Is there a way to programatically access the explain data in the mongo shell?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have the following query:

```
results = my_db.find(
  { 
    $query: { 
      start_time: { $lt: new Date(1419411454251) }, 
    }, 
    $explain: true 
  }
)
```

When running this in Robomongo, I can see the explain object in the output, but I don't know how to access it from the code. Can anyone help? I'm particularly interested in getting to the nscanned and nscannedObjects properties.

Comment: `results.indexOnly` for example since the return should be the explain since exlain acts as a query unto itself as it does in SQL etc

Comment: This gives me undefined, even though Robomongo says the value is false

Comment: try adding var to the start

Comment: I get the same output.

Comment: That is fasincating, with query operators this for some reason returns a db query object in the shell, if you use `deb.user.find().explain()` it will work